# Geb + Spock + groovy setup

Tags: groovy, gradle, spock, geb

So I've been attempting to get these tools running together, but I can't seem to get things setup properly.  Each time I am presented with the following error:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.spockframework.mock.MockController. Fix the build path then try building this project.
```

I've created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/4225717). When I run gradle chrome test I get the following output:

```
 gradle chrome test
 :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
 :compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
 :processResources UP-TO-DATE
 :classes UP-TO-DATE
 :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
 :compileTestGroovy FAILED

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
 > org/spockframework/mock/MockController

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

 BUILD FAILED
```

I'm using gradle 1.3, geb 0.7.2 and spock 0.7-groovy-2.0. I've also tried updating geb to utilize 0.9.0-RC-1. The gist above should have everything needed to see this same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you get when you run Spock 0.7 with Geb versions lower than 0.9.0-RC-1 (which aren't compatible with Spock 0.7). Double check your setup and perform a clean build.

Comment: Important thing to note is the location change from geb.codehaus.geb to org.gebish

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem. It turns out you need to use the groovy 1.8 version because the Geb/Spock integration jars haven't been upgraded to groovy 2.0 yet. The following setup worked for me:

```
dependencies {

    def seleniumVersion = "2.42.2"
    def phantomJsVersion = '1.1.0'
    def cargoVersion = '1.4.9'

    // selenium drivers
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
    compile("com.github.detro.ghostdriver:phantomjsdriver:$phantomJsVersion") {
        transitive = false
    }

    // geb
    compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-core:0.7.2'
    compile 'org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:0.7.2'

    // spock
    compile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.6-groovy-1.8'

    compile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.6@jar'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6@jar'

}
```

I posted my full script that includes cargo integration on my blog: http://www.openscope.net/2015/02/21/how-to-configure-gebspock-with-gradle/